# TFS2017 Sonarqube Code Coverage not displayed

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I have problem with displaying code coverage in Sonarqube from TFS2017. Did everything accordingly to steps described here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS
But with no luck…

[image]

Code coverage is visible in TFS2017, .trx .coverage and .coveragexml files are generated.
All unit tests are displayed correctly in Sonarqube but without coverage.

I’m using Sonarqube 7.2.1.14109

Comment: What happens if you don't set the additional property in the Prepare setup? (you're using v4 of the extension which should find the results automatically). If that doesn't work, add sonar.verbose=true to the additional properties and check the log for the Run Analysis step to see what is happening.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. Removing additional property sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/*.coveragexml does not work.

Comment: Did you get any error or warning info in your TFS build log. Since trx .coverage and .coveragexml files are generated properly, this seems not be a build/tfs related issue.  Besides have you tried to use the version SonarQube version 3 on TFS2017? Will this change the behavior?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/StefH/CoverageConverter to convert the .coverage to .coveragexml files.